# Python - Use lookup dictionary to set colour of pyplot scatter

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I am trying to colour the points of a scatter graph with the data sourced from a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
x = [5,7,12,0,19,56,40,16,36,17,81,50]
y = [20,26,37,40,8,63,13,28,47,91,26,2]
letter = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','E','B','A','C','F','D']
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : x, 'y' : y,'letter' : letter})
```

I have also set up a lookup dictionary, to decide which colour is assigned to which value in the 'letter' column:

```
letter_col = {'A':'blue', 'B':'red', 'C':'green', 'D':'yellow', 'E':'orange', 'F':'pink'}
```

Using the colour argument (c=) of the pyplot scatter function, how do I set the colour of the point, using letter_col?

Comment: did you try `plt.scatter(x=df.x, y=df.y, c=letter_col[df.y])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just create a `color` column within the dataframe and then pass it to the scatter function

```
x = [5,7,12,0,19,56,40,16,36,17,81,50]
y = [20,26,37,40,8,63,13,28,47,91,26,2]
letter_col = {'A':'blue', 'B':'red', 'C':'green', 'D':'yellow', 'E':'orange', 'F':'pink'}
letter = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','E','B','A','C','F','D']
colors = map(lambda x: letter_col.get(x, 'black'), letter)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : x, 'y' : y,'letter' : letter, 'color': colors})
```